# Unable to load the image for object recognition in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I am doing object recognition using mask RCNN in the google colab. I uploaded all the required files and directories in the working directory. This is the error I got after the execution of this python file. I have done it according to this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TikTv6PWDw&t=13s) until 9:50, I don't know how to execute ipynb file in another ipynb. so later, I followed this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSDbfGsxruA) from 10:14.

```
!python demo.py
```

the output for this code is

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Using TensorFlow backend.

Configurations:
BACKBONE                       resnet101
BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
BATCH_SIZE                     1
BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
COMPUTE_BACKBONE_SHAPE         None
DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.7
DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3
FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE     1024
GPU_COUNT                      1
GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM             5.0
IMAGES_PER_GPU                 1
IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT            3
IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  1024
IMAGE_META_SIZE                93
IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  800
IMAGE_MIN_SCALE                0
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE              square
IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3]
LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9
LEARNING_RATE                  0.001
LOSS_WEIGHTS                   {'rpn_class_loss': 1.0, 'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0}
MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14
MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28]
MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100
MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9]
MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56)
NAME                           coco
NUM_CLASSES                    81
POOL_SIZE                      7
POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000
POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000
PRE_NMS_LIMIT                  6000
ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33
RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              1
RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD              0.7
RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH                1000
TOP_DOWN_PYRAMID_SIZE          256
TRAIN_BN                       False
TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           200
USE_MINI_MASK                  True
USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
VALIDATION_STEPS               50
WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001


WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:541: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:66: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4432: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:2139: The name tf.nn.fused_batch_norm is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.nn.fused_batch_norm instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4267: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:2239: The name tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.image.resize_nearest_neighbor instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:341: The name tf.log is deprecated. Please use tf.math.log instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:399: add_dispatch_support.<locals>.wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:423: calling crop_and_resize_v1 (from tensorflow.python.ops.image_ops_impl) with box_ind is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
box_ind is deprecated, use box_indices instead
WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:720: The name tf.sets.set_intersection is deprecated. Please use tf.sets.intersection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:722: The name tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense is deprecated. Please use tf.sparse.to_dense instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py:772: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.cast` instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 76, in <module>
    model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)
  File "/content/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/model.py", line 2115, in load_weights
    f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 312, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 142, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open
OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 7340032, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 257557808)
```

i am completely beginner, so i am unable to identify the error
can anyone help me in finding out the error!
Thank You

Comment: Did your files download fully? It looks like some are corrupted as in the error message ```OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof...``` You should try re-downloading them.

Comment: after seeing your comment I have re-downloaded then that error was gone. `
<Figure size 1600x1600 with 1 Axes>`

Comment: what is the reason why it is not outputting the image in colab?

Comment: <Figure size 1600x1600 with 1 Axes> it is the output produced